# How to apply Dijktra algorithm on this graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

How to apply dijkstra algorithm on this graph?
I've been trying, but I cant figure out hows it going?

For example if we are to find shortest path from a to c, then shouldn't it be 3 as the shortest one go from a to b (1) and then b to c (2), so total 3 weight. However, answer is showing 4 that is direct from a to c.

Any help here?

[image]

Comment: The rows indicate vertex that is taken out from priority queue and how the distances change if there is a shorter path via that vertex. For the final results you should just check the last line (0, 1, 3, 2, 7).

Comment: I beg your pardon, but I don't understand how are you reading it.
for example:  row 2, B to A is 0, B to B is 1, B to C is 3..

Comment: ok, I will try to explain it properly (and post it as answer, since it will be better formatted and too long for comment)

Comment: thank you very much, much appreciated.

actually, I know how to do the shortest path, like keep visiting and ignoring the largest and continuing with the shortest.. but I cant figure out how's this is written in the table.

Comment: I think each row means "the algorithm has visited this node, now the distance to all the other nodes is....". So the table is showing all the steps of the algorithm. As an example, take the second row: *After considering/visiting node B, the distance to Node A is (still) 0, distance to B is still 1, distance to C is updated to be 3, distance to D is updated to be 2, distance to E is still infinity*

Comment: Answer provided by the book may not necessarily be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the Dijkstra algorithm the normal way and the shortest path from `a` to `c` is really 3. However, you should read the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) for Dijkstra to understand that table.

Firstly, Dijkstra returns an array (or another data structure, depending on implementation, for our purposes just say it's an array) of *all shortest paths from one given vertex to all vertices in graph*. In this case, if you want to use Dijkstra for determining the shortest path from `a` to `c`, you run it from `a` and then check the returned array for the path to `c`.

That table just shows the whole computing of shortest paths from `a`. It uses similar notation that [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ls1RqHCOPw), just that in the video they use numbers to mark the next iteration and here it's used the name of vertex that's taken out of the priority queue. In the pseudocode, you have `u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]`. The most left letter is the `u`. The whole row just shows if the best values changed and to what.

For example your path from `a` to `c`: In the first iteration, we are going from `a`, looking for neighbors. Since the neighbors of `a` are `c` (path of length 4), `b` (length 1) and `d` (path 3), we save these values (starting vertex is `a`, so the path from `a` to `a` is automatically 0 and `e` is not a neighbor of `a`, so there is no path to it yet). This is the first row of your table. For second iteration, we choose `b` (look at pseudocode why) - that's the first letter in the second row. Now we look at the neighbors of `b` and try to see whether we can improve some of the paths we marked in the first iteration. As you can see in the graph, there is a shorter way to `c` and `d` that we found directly from `a` (don't forget - you need to sum the path from `a` to `b` and from `b` to given vertex). The `e` is still not found, since it's also not a neighbor of `b`. The whole second row shows the best paths after we chose `b` from our priority queue.

We continue until all vertices are visited and fill all the rows in the table. The first letter is still the `u` from the pseudocode (vertex chosen from priority queue) and the rest of the row is how the paths improved in that iteration. If you try to imitate Dijkstra on your graph, you will see it. The last line is also the array of shortest paths that is returned.

To your comment (row 2, B to A is 0, B to B is 1, B to C is 3.) - that's not right, since you can see that shortest path from `b` to `c` is 2 (and there is no way how to get from `b` to `a`, so the distance will be infinity). However, to see that you would need to run Dijkstra from `b` as starting vertex.